# How do you build / use a slider with angular2?

Tags: angular

I need to use a banner slider in a angular 2 app. I have created a component called banner slider that holds the html for the slider and then im displaying it on the view from the app component.

the problem is, when the browser then loads the page all I get is three stacked li's where as when I use the code straight on the index.html the slider works fine? do I need to do something to get angular to work with jquery or is there a angular 2 speific slider that is good? if not does anyone know where to start with building one?

I am currently using unslider | unslider.com

Comment: This question could interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336019/angular2-with-jquery-ui-slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question could help you:

- [Angular2 with Jquery-ui Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336019/angular2-with-jquery-ui-slider)

The idea is to wrap the applying of the jquery plugin within an Angular2 component. This can be done within its `ngOnInit` method:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class Slider implements OnInit {
  elementRef: ElementRef;
  slideValue: number;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

ngOnInit() {
  jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).slider({
      range: false,
      orientation: "vertical",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 60,
      slide: (event, ui) => {
        (...)
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i looked at the post and just disregarded it thanks alot Thierry im going to put a simplified version that worked for my below :)